# Why I can't Receive String and It's null

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
public void save(String str) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

all I got is null:

[image: d]

[image]

Comment: I send a json post like  {"str" : "sasfafsfafa"}  but it's print null

Comment: It's a while since I played with Spring MVC, but maybe you need the `RequestBody` annotation on your method parameter? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

Comment: Thank you so much,I try to add @RequestBody,but It's Print like {"str" : "sasfafsfafa"} ,I just want "sasfafsfafa"

Comment: @TJSeason check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Spring where to get `str` from.

If you're sending the JSON

```
{ "str": "sasfasfafa" }
```

You'll need a class that deserialises from this and annotate the method parameter with `@RequestBody`.

```
public class StrEntity {
    private String str;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}

public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
    public void save(@RequestBody StrEntity entity) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(entity.getStr());
    }
}
```

If you just want to send a string as the request body (i.e. `sasfasfafa`) instead of the JSON document you can do this:

```
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
    public void save(@RequestBody String str) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

There is no way to send the JSON `{ "str": "sasfasfafa" }` as request body and only have a String as a method parameter in the controller.

Comment: What if I just want get one String param,and Receive  post by json, How do I write the code and the json,(Excuse me,My English is poor,can u understand what I mean?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestParam` annotation to get the parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
public void save(@RequestParam(name="str") String str) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: you mean (value="str"), I sen post request json { "str": "sasfasfafa" } the Httpstatu is  400,.And I use @RestController,It's any Different with @Controller?